# Extract href attribute value from response and save in separate file for each URL Jmeter

Tags: html, jmeter

Hi I am running a test scenario where I am taking relative URL's from the csv file and hitting it with the same after appending it to domain.
Now I want to extract all the href present in the body for each page hit and save in a separate file.
Say if I am hitting www.abc.com/url1 and this pages has 10 href than 1st file should be named as url1 and should contain these 10 href values.Similarly for all the other URL's

Please suggest as I am not an expert in Jmeter. I tried googling but didn't found an understandable way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

1. Add [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) as a child of the HTTP Request and configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `href`
   - CSS/JQuery Expression: just `a`
   - Attribute: `href`
   - Match No: `-1`

   This will extract all "href" attributes from all links into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

   ```
   href_1=http://foo.bar
   href_2=http://example.com
   ...
   href_matchNr=10
   ```
2. Then add Beanshell PostProcessor as a child of the same HTTP Request **after** the CSS JQuery Extractor. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   File csvFile = new File("/path/to/url1.csv");
   int hrefCount = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("href_matchNr"));
   for (int i = 1; i <= hrefCount; i++) {
       FileUtils.writeStringToFile(csvFile,vars.get("href_" + i) + System.getProperty("line.separator"), true);
   }
   ```

   where:

   - `vars` - an instance of [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class which provides read/write access to JMeter Variables
   - [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) - is the class from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) package which provides simple approach of reading and writing data

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on how you can overcome JMeter limitations by scripting and some form of Beanshell cookbook

Comment: That worked but can you let me know how can I only get href which are pointing to internal URLs like <a href="/test"> using this approach 
Also the script takes a single csv as output value... so will all the urls that are hit from the input csv file will get reported in this single file.

Can i also bifurcate the urls from one page from the other by any page name or something?

Comment: To get only URLs starting with `/` use `a[href^=/]` as the expression. `prev.getUrlAsString();` method returns current page URL.

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks a lot

Comment: What should be the reqular expression if i want to fetch all links in the page that contain www.abc.com only whether http or https?